# RHC setup gives mkdir error

Tags: ruby, openshift

I am trying to add an openshift origin server for the first time. using :

> rhc setup --server my.server.adr

but I get this error when it comes to Generate the token.

```
Generating an authorization token for this client ... C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir': No such file or directory @dir_s_mkdr - U: (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/auth/token_store.rb:34:in `[]='
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/auth/token_store.rb:14:in `put'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/auth/token.rb:50:in `save'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:243:in `block in login_stage'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:190:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:190:in `section'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:204:in `paragraph'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:337:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:237:in `login_stage'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:67:in `block in run'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:65:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:65:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/setup.rb:57:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:421:in `run_active_command'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

I can't find what's wrong, and what is the - U: after @dir_s_mkdir ?

any help or hint would be apreciated.

Comment: I would suggest logging a bug report here (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/describecomponents.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online), also, are you using this against your own openshift origin installation?  If not, you should not need to specify the server, just accept the default one.

Comment: There are some bugs with Ruby 2.2 and RHC on Windows. Try using an older version of Ruby like 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, I think it's a compatibility problem as you said with ruby 2.2

I didn't use another ruby version but I used a docker container instead.